# main.exe file is failed to run access is denied error in vs code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

when I try to run code it is showing the same error again and again

[image]

Comment: This seems less like a C (or VSCode) question and more like one about PowerShell. Have you searched up about the "Access denied" error? Maybe try opening PowerShell separately as admin and try `.\main` again.

Comment: Post the [code, the compilation command and the error as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6865932).

Comment: Have you tried to open the `powershell` in `admin` mode and run the script?

Comment: Never share your code as an image.